# Xcode can't enable in-app purchase

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I've an app with status Ready for Sell. App is available on app store.

Now I want to add new version with in-app purchase.
My app ID include in-app purchase. I added new version (with status Prepare for Submission ) and Non-Consumable to itunes connect.
On Xcode I updated app version.
When I click Capabilities -> In-App Purchase I have "an app id with identifier is not available ..." and on General tab: "none of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities in app purchase"
"Fix issue" dasn't help.

My other project with IAP works perfect.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

In the membership portal, under "Certificates and identifiers", when you look under the pros profiles, is the one in question still available and valid?

Comment: Do I need new Bundle ID for each version of my app or should I use one for each version ?
To be precisely: when I change app version to newer on Xcode have I to make new Bundle ID or leave first one ?

Comment: The App ID has nothing to do with your version. Just keep using the initial one your used for the project e.g. `com.company.app.somethingGreat` and if version 2 comes out then perhaps `com.company.app.somethingGreat2`